# Java: How to detect (and change?) encoding of System.console?

Tags: java, macos, encoding, console, character-encoding

I have a program which runs on a console and its Umlauts and other special characters are being output as ?'s on Macs. Here's a simple test program:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    System.out.println("höhößüä");
    System.console().printf( "höhößüä" );
}
```

On a default Mac console (with default UTF-8 encoding), this prints:

```
 h?h????
 h?h????
```

But after manually setting the Mac terminal's encoding to "Mac OS Roman", it correctly printed

```
 höhößüä
 höhößüä
```

Note that on Windows systems using System.console() works:

```
 h÷h÷▀³õ
 höhößüä
```

So how do I make my program...*rolleyes*..."run everywhere"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Epaga: have a look right [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20050208053951714). You can set the output encoding in a printstream - just have to determine or be absolutely sure about which is being set.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] argv) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String unicodeMessage =
    "\u7686\u3055\u3093\u3001\u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306f";

    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
    out.println(unicodeMessage);
  }
}
```

To determine the console encoding you could use the system command "locale" and parse the output which - on a german UTF-8 system looks like:

```
LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: 2 problems: 1) how do I know which encoding is set in the console? 2) is there any way to still work with System.console() ?

Comment: No, you cannot retain your code using `System.console()`, and I don't perceive it critical. `PrintStream` also has everything you want and it *does* work properly. +1 for the answer from me.

Comment: 1) You could use the system command "locale" and parse its output.

Answer (score 13):

Try the following command-line argument when starting your application:

`-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`

This changes the default encoding of the JVM for I/O operations.

You can also try:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "utf-8"));
```

Comment: problem with this is that I'm shipping this console program as a jar, so I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve the user having to add his own command line arguments.

Comment: @Epaga - use a bat file or some wrapper for the jar?

Comment: -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 is not a standard option and should be avoided.

Comment: @Bozho The second option helped for being able to print utf-8 (hebrew) to my console. However, my ultimate problem is mapping of servlet url patterns. When using hebrew urls in the url patterns the mappings are displayed (I checked on jconsole MBeans) as gibberish. I thought that fixing the console printing would also fix the mappings but it doesn't. Do you have any other suggestions?