# Output window in Netbeans 7.2 can't correctly display thai symbols

Tags: java, utf-8, netbeans-7, output-window

Need your help. I have an annoying issue: thai symbols can't be printed pretty in Netbeans 7.2 output window:

Output after System.out.println(...); ???????????????????[TH_WORD]

I changed netbeans.conf as mentioned, it doesn't help; I changed project properties->Sources encoding to UTF-8 and sources looks good, all thai symbols in sources are correctly printable. But how to change settings of NB output window?

Windows 7 64bit, Netbeans 7.2 (I run NB as "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2\bin\netbeans64.exe" --locale en_US)

Answer (score 2):

Solved thanks to conversation [Java: How to detect (and change?) encoding of System.console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415597/java-how-to-detect-and-change-encoding-of-system-console)

The solution was founded and applied:

PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");

use appropriate import java.io.*, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

For Azerbaijani language I tried this:

- added `System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF8"));` into my code. After this correction it changed ? marks into different symbols. The word **tədarük** before displayed as **t?dar?k**. But now it standed **tЙ™darГјk**
- then I added `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` into the Run arguments on Project properties, no way
- then tested with `-Duser.language=az`, result was the same
- changed the font on Output console (right click on console and on Settings window changed `Monospaced` font into `Arial`, nothing changed

It did not help. Only after changing Netbeans config it worked.
I opened netbeans.conf, in my case it was in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\etc folder, on linux it'll /usr/local/netbeans-7.4/etc/netbeans.conf

I added `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` into the end of `netbeans_default_options` just before the quotation mark. Restarted NetBeans. Now it works even with `Monospaced` font and without setting `-Duser.language` param.

So I needed only two things.

1. add `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` into `netbeans_default_options` in
   netbeans.conf
2. change output string encoding in your code: `System.setOut(new
   PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF8"));`

Comment: A variation of your second change would be to set `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` for _Properties > Run > VM Options_ within the project's properties instead. Then you wouldn't need to set the encoding for the `PrintStream` to _"UTF8"_ in the code, and you could just call `System.out.println()` in the usual way.

Comment: @skomisa , i didnd any printstrims, just first option and yours and its shows local language letters pretty ok now! Talking about  Apache Netbeans 12.5

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be to change the font being used for the console output window to one that includes Thai characters.  In Eclipse this is possible in the Preferences dialog.  It's been at least 5 years since I used NetBeans, but I'm 99% certain something similar is available there too.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but the main problem I can't find suitable settings. I can find and hold it in previous versions of NB, but not in this one 7.2. Please, if you've found it, let my weird attention to know.

Answer (score 0):

you can add system variable in mycomputer

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```