# Change console input encoding in NetBeans 8.0

Tags: java, input, encoding, console

I don't find the option in NetBeans 8.0 to change the console input encoding.

In Windows the console input encoding is Windows 1252 by default, but I want to change it to UTF-8.

Where is the option?

Thanks.

Edit:

I have found how to do it. Editing the file "netbeans.conf" from the "etc" directory located at the installation directory of NetBeans: in the "netbeans_default_options" option, add "-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8".

Comment: Instead of editing the question you can post an answer to your own question.