# Java Scanner and letters åäö

Tags: java, input

I want to input strings that may contain the letters åäö in Java, but Scanner converts them to some other character. I tried with utf-8 too:

```
String s1 = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
String s2 = new Scanner(System.in, "utf-8").nextLine();
System.out.println(s1 + "|" + (int)s1.charAt(0));
System.out.println(s2 + "|" + (int)s2.charAt(0));
System.out.println((int)'å' + "|" + (int)'?');
```

This yields:

```
å
å
?|8224
?|65533
229|63
```

All characters become 65533 with utf-8. Without utf-8, ä becomes 8222, ö becomes 8221, Å becomes 65533, Ä becomes 381, Ö becomes 8482.

Is there some alternative input method that allows for åäö?

I'm running java 8u25 and I'm running the program from the windows console.

Comment: Also, what happens when you write your output to a file?

Comment: You have three `println()` statements and five lines of output. What goes with what?

Comment: @Pshemo I guess that is not a problem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85 suggests the 229 code for the å is fine. Probably the Windows console has some encoding issues.

Comment: windows console don't use utf8 I think it use ISO 8859-1

Comment: @Pshemo No idea. How do I find out?

Comment: @Ted Hopp The first two are input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with Java, but with the windows console, which uses its own encoding. You can get it to display using the `chcp` command. Most likely it will be Codepage 850. In Java, you can then use this like

```
new Scanner(System.in, "Cp850")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the encoding for your output stream (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2415597/535871)):

```
String s1 = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
String s2 = new Scanner(System.in, "utf-8").nextLine();

PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println(s1 + "|" + (int)s1.charAt(0));
out.println(s2 + "|" + (int)s2.charAt(0));
out.println((int)'å' + "|" + (int)'?');
```

Comment: Does charAt work properly with multi-byte characters?  All of his tests are two-byte UTF-8 characters.

Comment: @zebediah49 - Once the characters are in memory, Java uses UTF-16; the only characters that `charAt()` doesn't handle well are surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows cmd.exe does not support UTF-8 encoding. You have to use [`WriteConsoleW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687401.aspx) and [`ReadConsoleW`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684958.aspx), or use the `chcp` command, like `new Scanner(System.in, "Cp850")`.