# Maven UTF-8 Compiler Fail

Tags: java, intellij-idea, utf-8, compilation

I am trying to develop a Maven Project, using IntelliJ IDEA, having all classes the `UTF-8` charset.

Unfortunately, when I compile my project, I got errors when printing some strings.

I am trying to print this: `Çorap, çorap`

I take this output after compile: `├çorap, ├ğorap`

I have already looked lots of questions and tried to add plugins, setting `sourceEncoding` but that doesn't work for me. When I decompile the jar, this is the string: `\u00e7orap, \u00c7orap`.

Comment: Can you please provide an example, or the code, that's giving the specified error?

Comment: No, there is no error. The code is just System.out.println, I don't get any fails/errors when I don't use Maven but on Maven, I get this strings.

Comment: When I wrote "error" I meant the erroneous string that's being outputted. Btw, have you tried the approach mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2415659/1346996) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24841904/1346996).

Comment: Yep, when I use thing in your answer I take the error what I said in up. If I do not use, I take a result like that "Ãorap"

Comment: Are you executing your code through IntelliJ or through the console?

Comment: Through the console.

Comment: What is the JVM property `file.encoding` set to?

Comment: When I print, it outputs UTF-8

Comment: If you don't use Maven why does this question has the Maven Tag?

Comment: I am using Maven, but I solved the problem. Thanks.