# Cygwin encoding difficulties

Tags: java, encoding, cygwin, system.out, system.in

Not sure whether this is a programming problem. I began to suspect so... but then I ran the Java program (executable jar) in question in a Windows console instead of a Cygwin one... and it ran fine: output accents fine, accented input accepted fine.  So what follows applies only to the Cygwin console.

I'm processing some French text. When accented characters are printed (`System.out`) a sort of "hashed box" is printed instead. I saw another question here about this but there was no solution or proper explanation given.

And when I enter accented characters these are read in incorrectly (Java `System.in`), e.g. "bénéfice" is then printed out (in the log which is handling encoding correctly) as "bÃ©nÃ©fice".

What is puzzling (perhaps) is that I am able to type "bénéfice" in the console. The font Deja Vu Sans Mono is meant to handle Unicode well, as I understand it. So... might this be something to do with the Java `System.in` and `System.out` streams???

For the avoidance of doubt, this is Cygwin on a Windows platform (does anyone use Cygwin on a non-Windows OS?).

I have tried changing the "Locale" and Character set and Font, by going Options --> Text.  Nothing changes these boxes.
At the moment settings are the default ones:
Font: Deja Vu Sans Mono
Locale: en_GB
Character set: UTF-8

At the command prompt, when I go

```
$ locale
```

I get

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Anyone know what I should do?

Comment: Cygwin is of course only for Windows. Please note that Java is not a cygwin application so it will likely ignore the cygwin locale setting.

Comment: Thanks. So... in practice what might this mean in terms of bytes and encodings and a possible solution?  Is there a way to get Java to send streams in a particular encoding?  I confess, encoding has always baffled me utterly.

Comment: This is most likely just a mismatch in the charset used by your java-instance and the cygwin console. Might be worthwhile to check the character-encoding used by your java-instance. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415597/java-how-to-detect-and-change-encoding-of-system-console) might also be quite helpful in solving this problem.

Comment: what code did you use to read string from `System.in`?

Comment: @Paul great! You've solved half the problem: `PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");`. Now I'm trying to work out how to get a `BufferedReader` do `readLine` with the right encoding...

Comment: @ZhongYu `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in) );`.  Presumably this is not using UTF8. Do you know how I solve that?

Comment: UTF-8 for InputStreamReader

Comment: You should post the entire code of reading from `in` then printing to `out`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Paul and Zhong Yu for the answers here.

To print to Cygwin do this sort of thing:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.print( outputString );
```

To read from Cygwin do this sort of thing:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8") );
String nextInputLine = br.readLine();
```

Slightly amazed that this question has not come up before re Cygwin.